# Downloaded file save with 0kb and damaged

Tags: php, file, download

I have a problem with download script 
when I download any file it is save with 0kb.
Any ideas? Here is my PHP script

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['fname'];
$fullpath = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/application/display/1358947404.pdf";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullpath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullpath);
?>
```

Comment: header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add content-length header as well .

Please try this:-

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['fname'];

$fullpath = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/application/display/1358947404.pdf";

$headers = get_headers($fullpath, 1);// use file absolute path here
$fsize = $headers['Content-Length'];

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullpath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullpath);
?>
```

Comment: In my case $headers['Content-Length'] display blank plz tell me what is problem?

Comment: please check absolute path in `get_headers()` function.

  `$fullpath = "http://yourdomain.com/directory/to/display/1358947404.pdf";`
  
 `print_r(get_headers( $fullpath , 1));`

Comment: look like Array ( [0] => [1] => //www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> [ [2] => [3] => [ [4] => [6] => )

Comment: Hey Niraj Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php how get_headers() work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you.

I have tested this in my localhost.

```
$file = $_GET['fname'];

$fullpath = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/application/display/1358947404.pdf";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullpath));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullpath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullpath);
```